# PYTHON How to add a column using numpy.where that includes data from the dataframe in the next row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Im really new to python and would appreciate your help.

I'm trying to add a column to my data frame in python. I'm using the following:

```
df['capital']=np.where(df['year']!=1960,2,df['GDP'])
```

Except, when I write GDP what I really want is the GDP for the year 1961. Any idea how I can include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.shift()` to use the `GDP` value in the next row. By default a `1` is passed to `.shift()`, but you can also pass `-1` or `2`, etc to compare up or down as many rows as you'd like:

```
df['capital'] = np.where((df['year'] != 1960), 2, df['GDP'].shift())
```